# How to catch network error and redirect to html page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Developing a C#, MVC5 web app....

In one of my class methods, when I receive a network error (ie can't connect to database) I want to redirect to an HTML error page. What's the best way to handle this?

Here's what I tried so far....

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string MyMethod(SettingKey key)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var cnn = new dbContext())
            {
                return cnn.MySettings.Where(s => s.Key == key.ToString()).AsNoTracking().Select(s => s.Value)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.InnerException != null && e.InnerException.Message.Contains("A network-related or instance-specific error occurred"))
            {
                return Redirect("error_network_related.html");
            }
            return "";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm specifically trying to navigate to error_network_related.html in the root of my application whenever the network is down and the db cannot be accessed.

So, my question has to do with (1) the best way to catch this specific network-related error (db down) and (2) best way to redirect to the error page.

Other suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: `the best way to catch this specific network-related error (db down)` If you take your DB down, and run this code what **exact** exception is thrown?

Comment: I did that. But, what do I look at, the HResult? @mjwills

Comment: Can you update your post with the `Type`, `StackTrace` and `ToString` of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Action / Controller to handle the Error message/UI you need to show. Then use MVC Controller `OnException` to Customize Responses and then Return the specific action using `RedirectToAction().`

`OnException` is similar to `HandleErrorAttribute` but provides more flexibility. It works with all HTTP status codes, and not just 500 level responses. It also gives you the ability to log the errors!

```
public class UserMvcController : Controller
{
   protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   {
      filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

      //Redirect or return a view, but not both.
      filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "ErrorHandler");
      // OR 
      filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
      {
         ViewName = "~/Views/ErrorHandler/Index.cshtml"
      };
   }
}
```

This is a suggested approach :)